# Remote Debugging Fails with IntelliJ but works with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, intellij-idea, remote-debugging, websphere-liberty

I'm attempting to debug a program running in WebSphere Liberty Profile, so I run this on the server:

```
./server debug
```

This prints out

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 7777
```

In IntelliJ IDEA, version 13.1.3, I try:

Run > Edit Configurations > + > Remote.

I pick Socket, Attach, fill in the hostname, and enter the port number of 7777, give it a name, and then OK.

Run > Debug > Pick the name I just gave it.

It opens a debugger tab and after ~30 seconds it displays the message

```
Error running (debugger configuration name):
Unable to open debugger port:
java.net.ConnectException "Connection timed out: connect"
```

(Line breaks added to make it easier to read).

I can then launch Eclipse, Kepler Service Release 2, and do

Run > Debug Configurations... > Remote Java Application > New > give it a name, pick Socket Attach, give it the host name and port number of 7777, click Apply, and Debug.

And it works just fine.

The fact that I can run Eclipse and have it work fine and IntelliJ and have it fail at the same time indicates to me that the problem isn't anywhere on my server and it's not an issue with my network connection.

It seems to me that the problem must lie somewhere in how I've set up IntelliJ. So my question is: what could I have done right with Eclipse that I'm getting wrong with IntelliJ?

Comment: Do you maybe have a local firewall installed that blocks network connections from IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: @yole - Maybe, but if that's the case I did it over a year ago and I'm not quite sure how to change it. I will investigate and report back tomorrow!

Comment: @yole - I disabled the firewall on my local machine and suddenly IntelliJ IDEA was able to work just like Eclipse does. Thanks! I'll have to look into adjusting my firewall to be more fine-grained so that IntelliJ can get through without disabling the firewall altogether. Thanks again - if you post that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message shows that IntelliJ IDEA can't establish a network connection to the debuggee process. One common reason for this problem is a local firewall rule that blocks network connections from IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I'm using Symantec Endpoint Protection on Windows 7. To allow IntelliJ through I had to right click on the shield in the system tray, pick "Open Symantec Endpoint Protection", Click on the Status tab on the right, then click Network Threat Protection's Options button, pick "View Application Settings", scroll to "idea.exe", right click it, and pick "Allow". This took around 2 hours to find the option, thus why I'm providing these details.